# iOS: Can't scroll between UITableViews in paged UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView, in which I want to contain a number of UITableViews, each one being a page. I've added them to my scroll view, and verified that the frames of the UITableViews are set correctly. The first UITableView is displayed correctly, but it will not let me scroll horizontally to see the others. Here's the code I'm using to at the table views:

```
scrollView.delegate=self;
scrollView.scrollEnabled=YES;
tableViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:recipOrgs.count];
for (NSDictionary *orgDict in recipOrgs) {

    int index = [recipOrgs indexOfObject:orgDict];


    NSLog(@"Creating table view for index: %d",index);
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * index;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;

    OrganizationTableView *tableView = [[OrganizationTableView alloc] init];

    tableView.index=index;
    tableView.parentCon=self;
    tableView.dataSource=tableView;
    tableView.delegate=tableView;

    [tableViews addObject:tableView];
    [scrollView addSubview:tableView];
    [tableView setFrame:frame];

}
```

Any ideas why this isn't working? As I mentioned, I checked the x values of the UITableView origins, and I get 0, 320, 640, etc. like I would expect.

Comment: Why you create multiple tableviews inside scrollview? Use single tableview with sections.

Comment: I want to scroll horizontally.

Comment: Use UICollectionview instead of UITableview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably forgetting to set the `contentSize` for your `scrollView`.

```
scollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(recipOrgs * CGRectGetWidth(scrollView.frame), CGRectGetHeight(scrollView.frame));
```

But you should probably consider using `UICollectionView` instead of `UIScrollView`, then you get reuse logic for free and you do not have to worry about the `contentSize`.

Comment: You do this even when using AutoLayout?

Comment: Hm, no you don't but I do not see `autolayout` in the code you provided, your operating with `frame`s.

Comment: The .xib says it is using AutoLayout, but your contentSize suggestion worked. I will look into switching to UICollectionView. Thanks!